# How to open file in browser using brackets text editor

Tags: html, browser, text-editor, brackets

I know that with brackets text editor,you can view files in a browser using 'live preview' but that requires a server connection and I don't have one.

I simply just want to run a html file in a web browser using brackets.Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: AFAIK, Brackets did not require any server connection. Check this, https://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/brackets/live-preview

Comment: Do you have Xampp or another local host installed?